# REGEX Match a String

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Given the following URIs sample:

```
 /index.site.rooms.98.html

 /index.site.rates.665678.html
```

I need to capture the string which identifies the page with REGEX:

Rooms

Rates

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$page =~ /^\/index\.site\.(.*?)\.(\d+)\.html$/;
my $room = $1;
my $num = $2;
```

Perl regex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately. I am not using Perl, this is for Google Analytics and it will replace matched string on the fly. Is there a way to store one string under $1 using plain regular expressions?

Comment: @Matias After a quick search it seems GA uses perl compatible regular expressions (PCRE), not all features are supported but this should work.

Comment: I am not sure, in fact, its quite limited what you can do.  There are two input boxes, one for Search for and another to Output >.  I imagine there should be some kindof built-in variables to use but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
(rooms|rates).[0-9]+